# function in flask did not return valid response

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request,session
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
import Distilbert as d
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd



app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = b'_5#ysujsq"Flli\n\xec]/'

@app.route("/" , methods = ["GET","POST"])
def hello():
    return render_template("index.html")



@app.route("/su", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def data_value():
    data = []
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session['context'] = request.form['context']
        session['question'] = request.form['question']
        data.append(d.Question_answer(session['context'],session['question']))
    df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Context', 'Question', 'Answer'])
   
    return render_template("home.html", td = data)
    

@app.route("/data", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def Insert_data():
    if 'context' not in session:
        return redirect(url_for('data_value'))
    data = [d.Question_answer(session['context'], session['question'])]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Context', 'Question', 'Answer'])
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            d.insert_into_db(df, cursor) 
            print('parsed using normal parsing1_div .')

        except Exception as ex:
            print('db fail1 ')
            print(ex)
        return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The view function for 'Insert_data' did not return a valid response. The function either
returned None or ended without a return statement.I am getting this error when I insert data into database.

Answer (score 1):

```py
@app.route("/data", methods = ["GET","POST"])
def Insert_data():
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST': # For POST method
        ...
        return render_template("index.html")
    # ↓ You need to add this block ↓
    else: # For GET method
        return <>
```

You return nothing if `request.method` is not `POST` (actually here is no `return` at all), but route is accepting `"GET"` and `"POST"` methods